# How to display data in table using Keystone6 component in custom page so it looks same?

Tags: keystonejs, keystonejs6

I have build custom page in Keystone6 using this [docs](https://keystonejs.com/docs/guides/custom-admin-ui-pages)

Now I am getting data from GraphQL query.

```
{
    "members": [
        {
            "__typename": "Member",
            "id": "ckwluj7jd1675l4l8e9yfcwtt",
            "name": "User 2",
            "companyName": "company1",
        },
        {
            "__typename": "Member",
            "id": "ckwltsw620162l4l88g8ox4zo",
            "name": "User 1",
            "companyName": "company2",
        },
        {
            "__typename": "Member",
            "id": "ckwm061f8436554l8ab4ic3dsd5o",
            "name": "User 3",
            "companyName": "",
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I am trying to display it on custom page but I am not sure how to use Keystone6 admin component to display data.

Answer (score 0):

Ronald here from the Keystone Team.

At the moment there’s no way to do this using official Keystone components. We’re working on a next-gen Admin UI in 2022 that will make it easier for you to achieve this.